# SQL select with preference on column values

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am new to SQL and I would like to ask about how to select entries based on preferences and grouping.

```
+----------+----------+------+
| ENTRY_ID | ROUTE_ID | TYPE |
+----------+----------+------+
|        1 |       15 |    0 |
|        1 |       26 |    1 |
|        1 |       39 |    1 |
|        2 |       22 |    1 |
|        2 |       15 |    1 |
|        3 |       30 |    1 |
|        3 |       35 |    0 |
|        3 |       40 |    1 |
+----------+----------+------+
```

With the table above, I would like to select 1 entry for each `ENTRY_ID` with the following preference for the returned `ROUTE_ID`:

1. IF TYPE = 0 is available 
   for any one of the entries with the same `ENTRY_ID`, return the minimum `ROUTE_ID` for all entries with `TYPE = 0`
2. IF for the same `ENTRY_ID` only `TYPE = 1` is available, return the minimum `ROUTE_ID`

The expected outcome for the query will be the following:

```
+----------+----------+------+
| ENTRY_ID | ROUTE_ID | TYPE |
+----------+----------+------+
|        1 |       15 |    0 |
|        2 |       15 |    1 |
|        3 |       35 |    0 |
+----------+----------+------+
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4):

You can group by both `TYPE` and `ENTRY_ID`, and then use the `HAVING` clause to filter out those where `TYPE` is not the minimal value for that record.

```
SELECT ENTRY_ID, MIN(ROUTE_ID), TYPE
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY ENTRY_ID, TYPE
HAVING TYPE = (SELECT MIN(s.TYPE) FROM MyTable s WHERE s.ENTRY_ID = MyTable.ENTRY_ID)
```

This relies on type only being able to be 0 or 1. If there are more possible values, it will only return the lowest type.

Comment: Was working on a query until I saw your answer. Your answer returns the requested values http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a8f00/9

Comment: The code works fine, thanks! However, I was having performance issues with this code that it takes very very long time to finish the Make Table Query. Is there anything I can do to speed it up?

Comment: The main thing you can do is add a composite index with ROUTE_ID and ENTRY_ID. But unless the table you're running this against is very large, this shouldn't take long at all. You can also use `WHERE` instead of `HAVING` when benchmarking this (and then it goes before `GROUP BY` and not after), but I think that'll be slower, not faster.

Answer (score 3):

If you want complete rows, use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.route_id = (select top 1 t2.route_id
                    from t as t2
                    where t2.entry_id = t.entry_id
                    order by iif(t2.type = 0, 1, 2),  -- put type 0 first
                             t2.route_id asc  -- then the first route_id
                   );
```

This has the advantage that it can return more than just  the three columns you show in the question.

Comment: Note that this is tagged ms-access, so the syntax is `TOP 1` not `TOP(1)` and it has the nasty habit of running into an error if there are ties when using `TOP 1` in a subquery. As long as `route_id` is unique that won't happen though.

Comment: Also, it is `IIF()` not `IFF()`. Please join me @ErikA, in [recommending](https://access.uservoice.com/forums/319956-access-desktop-application/suggestions/37193662-upgrade-access-sql-dialect-to-current-ansi-standar) to the Access team to upgrade the database's dialect to current ANSi standards as this solution could work great with CTE and/or window functions. But at very least have Access join the RDBMS world with portable syntax such as `CASE` statements.